# Hosting IE 8 In WinForms and Opening a PDF

Tags: c#, vb.net, file, internet-explorer-8, acrobat

We have a form that hosts the WebBrowser control. That is the only control on the form.

We pass the form the file path of a temporary PDF file and it does:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(Me._PathToPdf)
```

When the form is closing, it navigates away from the PDF file:

```
WebBrowser1.Hide()
WebBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank")

Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
Loop
```

Once the form is closed, the calling class then deletes the temporary PDF file.

This process works great... until we installed Internet Explorer 8. For some reason, the combination of IE8 and Adobe Acrobat 8 (or 9) causes an extra file lock handle to be placed on the temporary PDF file. The extra lock handle does not go away until the entire application is shut down. I should also mention that there are no locks on the file until the file is opened by Acrobat.

We can reproduce this on multiple machines and it is always the combination of IE8 and Adobe Acrobat Reader. We can install Foxit Reader 3 instead of Adobe Acrobat and things work fine. Likewise, we can run the app on a machine with IE7 and Adobe Acrobat, and things work fine. But, when you mix the magic potion of IE 8 and Acrobat, you end up with a mess.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting an extra file lock that persists until the end of the application?

Thanks.

An example application that demonstrates my problem can be found here: [PDFLockProblemDemo.zip](http://www.centrolutions.com/downloads/PDFLockProblemDemo.zip)

Comment: Alright, we couldn't find any good solutions to this problem, so we've resorted to using the ActiveX Acrobat Reader control on a form. This has unfortunately tied us to a version of Acrobat Reader, but it was necessary to get the version out the door.
I'm closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the real problems is using a `WebBrowser` control to host the Adobe Reader web browser plugin to display PDFs. Isn't there a better way to display PDFs directly without introducing a dependency on a web browser? Doesn't Adobe  provide an SDK or an ActiveX control you can host directly inside your form?

---

UPDATE: I looked around and found [this post](http://www.ureader.com/message/819807.aspx) where they access an Adobe ActiveX control (`AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF`) and simply call:

```
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile("mypdf.pdf");
axAcroPDF1.Show();
```

Comment: Yes, we have actually resorted to using the COM object provided by Adobe Acrobat. However, this is less than ideal because now are directly tied to Adobe Acrobat and must put that program as a prerequisite to our application. Before, we just required a PDF viewing application (Acrobat or Foxit most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

Still no solution found, but more info:
Previously I had tested with XP Pro, Acrobat *.x and .NET 2.0 (built with VS 2005).  Since then, I have also tested in a variety of scenarios that include Vista, Acrobat 9.x and .NET 3.5 (built with VS 2008).

Same results though: as long as the browser is IE8, the PDF file doesn't get released when you call Dispose() on the WebBrowser control.  It does get released when the app is closed, but that doesn't help us...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that accurately describes what we're running into, as well.

Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that will not require any temporary files.

I was forced to create a solution, after I was not in the mood of rewriting all my code to use temporary files.

So, here's what you do.

1. Create a list of strings to hold files to delete 
   `Dim filesToDelete As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)`
2. You need to set the webbrowser to another pdf file, 
   (I created a blank one - black or white; whatever works for you). 
   So like `webbrowser1.navigate("blank.pdf" )`
3. Add the file to be deleted to a list of strings. so `filesToDelete.Add(filename)`
4. Now, here's the trick. The resources will not be released until you get out of this event. 
    So you need to do a focus on something else that will cause another event to be fired. 
    In my case, I was using a treeview to view the pdf.
   So, after marking the file for deletion using the method above, 
    i would set the treeview to a different file. 
   So in the `TreeView1_BeforeSelect` method, I did the obvious:
   `If filesToDelete.Count > 0 Then`
             `For Each f As String In filesToDelete`
                    `File.Delete(f)`
             `Next`
            `filesToDelete.Clear()`
     `End If`
   You can adopt your own event, but I'm sure after doing the marking for the delete, you can find something to do that will cause another event to fire. Just follow the flow of your code, what happens next.

So there you have it. Hope this helped someone.

Comment: Instead of firing an event you can just call ```Application.DoEvents()``` and then do the deletes.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem  with IE8 and Acrobat.  In our case we simply needed to be able to overwrite the temporary PDF and redisplay it.  We found that we could simply open the PDF, write 0 bytes then close.  After that we would open the file and write the new PDF information and then redisplay the temporary file.

In summary, we did not solve the file locking problem, instead we just left the file handle attached and reused the file until the user closed the app.

Hope this helps.